# Why is the file I uploaded locked by ColdFusion 10?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to delete the file if not a spreadsheet, but keep getting the following error when I uploaded testFile.text:
ColdFusion could not delete the file D:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\work\Catalina\localhost\tmp\testFile.text

I verified its not a permission issue, because if I go back and execute the code to try to delete the file again, it will work.

```
<cffile action="upload" destination="#dest#" filefield="xlsfile" result="upload" nameconflict="makeunique">


<cfif upload.fileWasSaved>
    <cfset theFile = dest & upload.serverFile>

    <cfif isSpreadsheetFile(theFile)>
        <cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#theFile#" query="data" headerrow="1">
        <cfset showForm = false>
    <cfelse>
        <cfscript>
            thisFile = theFile;
            fileRead = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream");
            thisThread = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.Thread");
            loopCT = 1;
            while(1 EQ 1)
{
    try
    {
        fileRead.init(thisFile);
        break;
    }
    catch(any ecpt)
    {
        thisThread.sleep(1000);
    }
    incrementValue(loopCT);
    if(loopCT GT 60)
    {
        fileRead.close();
        return;
    }
}

loopCT = 1;
while(1 EQ 1)
{
    sizeA = fileRead.available();
    thisThread.sleep(1000);
    sizeB = fileRead.available();
    if(sizeA EQ sizeB)
    {
        thisThread.sleep(1000);
        sizeC = fileRead.available();
        if(sizeC EQ sizeB)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    incrementValue(loopCT);

    if(loopCT GT 60)
    {
        fileRead.close();
        return;
    }
}
fileRead.close();

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>


        </cfscript>

        <!--cffile action="delete" file="#theFile#"-->
        <cfset errors = "The file was not an Excel file.">
        <span style="font-size:medium;font-weight:bold; color:red"><p>The file was not an excel file!<p></span>
        <input type="button" value="TRY AGAIN" class="button" onClick="window.location='bulk_upload.cfm'">
        <br><br><br>
    </cfif>
    <cfset errors = "The file was not properly uploaded.">

</cfif>
```

Comment: Yes. Not working. do I need to do thisFile = '#theFile#';

Comment: (Edit) Define "not working". If you are getting an error, include the error message. BTW, you should not need to do anything. [Unscoped variables are placed in the `variables` scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd0.html). Any variable in that scope can be be accessed from cfml or cfscript within the same .cfm script.

Comment: I added the remaining code so you can see what I'm trying to do.
I'm trying to verify a file is not locked on the webserver before deleting it, but when I go to delete it I get "could not delete for unknown reason" in the coldfusion stack trace"

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Sorry...I reposted code and removed the actual question. Edited now.

Comment: Variables set outside cfscript are avaialable outside that script block, and vice versa.  If that were case, your error message would tell you that you have an undefined variable.  To troublshoot this, strip your code down to uploading the file and setting the variable.  Then add code to delete the file.  If that fails, look in the specified directory and see if the file is actually there.

Comment: You are correct. I was able to delete it. So the variable is not the issue any longer. The issue is the lock on the file that prevents it from being delete. I have not found a workaround.

Comment: Why is there a random `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`?

Comment: ""... the variable is not the issue any longer. The issue is the lock on the file..." Can you pls revise your question to actually ask the question you need answered, removing all the bumpf about CFScript.

Comment: Updated the question, as requested.

Comment: The problem is probably caused by `isSpreadsheetFile()`. For some reason, when you use that function on certain files, it locks them for a while at the OS level. I'm still on CF9, so obviously this isn't a new problem, but the only other place I've seen it mentioned is in the comments at the bottom of [this post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/5/31/ColdFusion-Sample--Upload-and-Parse-an-Excel-File) on Ray Camden's blog. I haven't found a solution yet. I have found that you can still write to the locked file, but that hasn't really gotten me anywhere, unfortunately.

Comment: I never did find the cause of the problem. Instead I created a temp folder that holds all excels uploaded and doesn't delete any. I would never do this on code outside the firewall, but it is inside the firewall and not accessible from the outside. Ironically, the customer came back to me and wanted to be able to store all excel file uploaded, so my solution satisfied them. I didn't feel so bad either, because this application is being re-written as an MVC .net solution in less than a year.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer Glad to hear that your cloud had a silver lining :). I gave up on deleting the files and decided to settle for deleting their content via `<cffile action="write" file="#path#" output="" addnewline="false"/>`. When I get around to it I'll probably schedule a task to delete all the 0 byte files, but at least now I can feel like I've done _something_ to clean up after myself.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue with regards to cfimage locking the file and preventing deletion.  The solution I came up with follows.  Maybe someone can adapt to their situation:

```
<cflock name="[lockName]" timeout="5" >

   <cfcache action="flush">

    <!---[] Replace cfimage read function (CF BUG work around)  --->
   <cfscript>

      imageObj   = createObject( "java", "java.awt.Toolkit" );
      imagetools = imageObj.getDefaultToolkit();
      objImage   = imagetools.getImage( "#fullpath#" );
      <!---Whatever image I need from the image, or file...--->
      <!---such as ---- myImageStruct["width"] = objImage.getWidth();--->

      <!--- and then flush the object--->
      objImage.flush();

  </cfscript>

</cflock>
```